# How many partitions set in constructing Non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

I am learning the measure theory and having a not so related problem in constructing the non measurable set. Let's consider the interval $[0,1]$, and define the equivalence class in such interval by $[x]=\{x+r\mid r\in\mathbb{Q},x+r\in [0,1]\}$.

My visualisation as follows, we anchor arbitrary element in $[0,1]$ and construct a first equivalence class denoted by [x], now we move on to another element $x'$ in $[0,1]$ to have another equivalence class. If $x'$ differ $x$ by a rational number it must in $[x]$, so that $x'$ has to be differ $x$ by a irrational. This construction process goes to infity

Here is the question:  I've seen someone claim we don't know how many partition sets here, countably of uncountably infinite, but I think it must be uncountably infinite as we have uncountable infinite irrationals in $[0,1]$.

Thank you for any comments

Comment: You are correct: there are in fact $|\Bbb R|$ equivalence classes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Cheers